# How to update texture during runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, directx, sharpdx

I am working on a HoloLens application. In this application I would like to be able to render websites, and move their positions. 
I have a lot of this working already, I have a XAML application with a webview that renders the website. And from this XAML application, I run a DirectX application that should display it.

I thought that would be the hard part, but the thing I really can't seem to figure out is how to update the texture of a cube during runtime. 
I have adapted the template of the spinningcube example to show a texture instead of the rainbow comes with. I would like to replace this texture with the bytearray I got from the webview.

I use this after the update method of SpinningCubeRenderer thats in the DirectX UWP template

```
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(newTextureBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
SharpDX.DataBox box = new SharpDX.DataBox(pointer);
//updatingTexture = new Texture2D(pointer);

deviceResources.D3DDeviceContext.UpdateSubresourceSafe(ref box, textureResource.Resource, 1);
pinnedArray.Free();
newTextureBytes = null;
```

TextureResource is the reference to the texture currently on the cube. Which I would like to adapt to the new texture.

I could not find a clear source on how to use UpdateSubresourceSafe, and after many tries I ended up with a corrupted memory warning.
Could anyone help me get started on how to swap a texture during runtime?

Comment: You need to create a new texture-ressource(shaderRessourceView if i remind it right) with the image-data you want to render.

The only thing to keep always in mind is that there is a renderloop if the renderer is processing the ressource(your texture) is locked and a manipulation will always fail at this point. So try to swap the texture in between and do not manipulate a texture that is currently used by the shader just swap it with another one instead.